# What is the difference between scheme-send-definition and scheme-send-last-sexp

Tags: emacs, scheme, elisp

It seems scheme-send-definition and scheme-send-last-sexp works with same result in gnu emacs. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

`scheme-send-definition` sends the current definition; the one point is located in.
`scheme-send-last-sexp` sends the s-expression immediately preceding point.